# Java Regex expression to match content within parenthesis

Tags: java, regex

I am currently working on a calculator project. I am working on the lexer. My intent is to create a calculator that can take inputs such as

```
5+3

4*8

3*(4+2)
```

and return an answer. I am attempting to create regular expressions that can split these up into tokens. I want to split expressions in parenthesis into a single token that will later be solved recursively. I am able to match my numbers and operators correctly, but I can't get it to work for my parenthesis expressions. Here is my current regular expression:

```
String tokenPatterns ="(?<NUMBER>-?[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+|-?[0-9]+)" //match any integer or decimal number
            + "|(?<OPERATOR>\\+|-|/|\\*)" //match operators     
            + "|(?<UNIT>in|pt)" //match a few units
            + "|(?<WHITESPACE>\\S+)" //match whitespace - is just discarded later, most likely unnecessary
            + "|(?<PAREN>\\([^\\n]*\\))"; //match any character series in parentheses, excluding newline
```

My testing has been successful for all of these except the parenthesis one. My understanding is that what I have written for parenthesis should match:

open parenthesis followed by any number of any characters excluding newline followed by close parenthesis

but when I give it the input of -34*(5+2), it only matches -34 and /.

Does anybody have an explanation or tip? Let me know if you need more context or clarification, and I will do my best to respond quickly. Thanks!

Comment: You might find sime inspiration in my project `rcalc` that does pretty much the same. There's a tokenizer class which splits expression into tokens. https://github.com/MightyPork/rcalc/tree/master/src/net/mightypork/rcalc

Comment: I might be wrong here, but i'm pretty sure Java doesn't support recursive REs (which you'd need in order to match parens correctly).  This is part of why lexing and parsing are usually done separately.  Matching up parens is the kind of thing a parser does; the lexer just reports each `(` or `)` as a token.

Comment: That looks very helpful for my current project...I will definitely start inspecting that! Thank you!

Comment: Really? I was thinking that inside my solver, I would create a new lexer object with the token in parenthesis, and solve it first to replace it with a new token. If that will not work, I will definitely need to rethink my structure.

Comment: Really.  Consider `((2*3)/6)-(0+1)`, for example.  Most REs will either capture too little (up to the first `)`) or too much (up to the last `)`).  Matching just the first term would be a royal pain.

Comment: That is very true. I didn't think of that. It definitely will be unable to solve something like that in my current structure. I will use the rcalc to find inspiration for a more effective calculator model.

Comment: A simple expression evaluator that functions like a stack would be an optional soultion. Start with a stack containing (, Push each symbol to stack. When a ) is encountered pop the preceding operands a operator and evaluate and push back that to stack. Continue until all chars are pushed/processed. Push a last ) and evaluate the remaining chars on stack.

Comment: It wouldn't be difficult to create a regular expression that would correctly match paren groups, but the regular expression would not run efficiently for larger expressions.

Comment: @mbomb007, matching nested expression would be a challenge with regex, as pointed by cHao.